# postgresql table constraint not rejecting bad inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table to log matches between users. All matches are 1v1 so there's always 2 users in a match, 1 of which must be the winner and the other which must be the loser, unless it's a tie.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    match_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_1_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    user_2_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    winner_id bigint REFERENCES users(user_id),
    loser_id bigint REFERENCES users(user_id),
    tied boolean,
    CONSTRAINT check_winner_loser_tied CHECK (
        (user_1_id != user_2_id) AND
        (
            (winner_id = user_1_id AND loser_id = user_2_id AND tied = FALSE) OR
            (winner_id = user_2_id AND loser_id = user_1_id AND tied = FALSE) OR
            (tied = TRUE AND winner_id = NULL AND loser_id = NULL)
        )
    )
);
```

As you can see above, I've added a table constraint to enforce the conditions I described above, however I'm still able to insert invalid data into the table, examples:

```
INSERT INTO matches (user_1_id, user_2_id, winner_id, loser_id, tied)
VALUES (1, 2, 1, 2, TRUE); -- can't be winner & loser if it's a tie!
```

And also:

```
INSERT INTO matches (user_1_id, user_2_id, winner_id, loser_id, tied)
VALUES (1, 2, NULL, NULL, FALSE); -- must be a winner & loser if no tie!
```

What am I doing wrong?

More info, if helpful: `SELECT version();` returns `PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit`.

Comment: `winner_id = NULL` should never be true, try `winner_id IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks, that helped solve the 1st case (tie = true with winner & loser)! However, the 2nd case is still possible (tie = false with null winner & null loser).

Comment: Don't know why it fails the 2nd case, but your datamodel is a bit too complicated. Why don't you replace the `winner_id`, `loser_id`, `tied` with a simple column with three values (0,1,2)? 0=tie, 1=1st user won, 2=nd user won.

Comment: I had considered that, but settled on the current version to make some other queries simpler. @joanolo correctly answered below, I had to use the `DISTINCT FROM` comparison operator instead of `=` when comparing potentially `NULL` values.

Comment: @kfedorov91: Check also the *alternative* added to my answer. It is a much more verbose way of doing things, but it normally makes your life easier both debugging your constraints, and later on analyzing what actually went wrong with your data.

Comment: @kfedorov91: PostgreSQL doesn't support computed columns, but you can easily recreate those three columns in a view using some CASEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint contain one mistake: handling NULLS, you're using

```
(winner_id = user_1_id AND loser_id = user_2_id AND tied = FALSE) OR
(winner_id = user_2_id AND loser_id = user_1_id AND tied = FALSE) OR
(tied = TRUE AND winner_id = NULL AND loser_id = NULL)
```

when you should use

```
(winner_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM user_1_id AND loser_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM user_2_id AND tied = FALSE) OR
(winner_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM user_2_id AND loser_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM user_1_id AND tied = FALSE) OR
(tied = TRUE AND winner_id IS NULL AND loser_id IS NULL)
```

All comparisons

```
(value = NULL)
```

return NULL in SQL three-state logic, for the = operator.

If you want to use only two-state logic, you use the [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) comparison predicate.

Check everything out at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c56873d70de2d44064b7b78c332769f2)*

---

**Alternatives**: Checks are more informative if you use *semantinc naming* and make them smaller. You'd use, for instance:

```
CONSTRAINT check_users_different 
    CHECK (user_1_id <> user_2_id),
CONSTRAINT check_when_tied_no_winner_and_no_loser
    CHECK (CASE WHEN tied 
               THEN winner_id IS NULL AND loser_id IS NULL
               ELSE true
           END),
CONSTRAINT check_when_not_tied_winner_not_null
    CHECK (CASE WHEN not tied
               THEN winner_id IS NOT NULL
               ELSE true
           END),
CONSTRAINT check_when_not_tied_loser_not_null
    CHECK (CASE WHEN not tied
               THEN loser_id IS NOT NULL
               ELSE true
           END),
CONSTRAINT check_when_not_tied_one_user_wins_the_other_loses
    CHECK (CASE WHEN not tied
               THEN (user_1_id = winner_id AND user_2_id = loser_id) OR
                    (user_1_id = loser_id  AND user_2_id = winner_id)
               ELSE true
           END)
```

(I know: this is far more verbose, and the `CASE WHEN` could be simplified by just using ORs or ANDs. I find it writing like this that it makes it clearer.)

And then you'd get more informative errors:

```
INSERT INTO matches (user_1_id, user_2_id, winner_id, loser_id, tied)
VALUES (1, 2, 1, 2, TRUE); -- can't be winner & loser if it's a tie!
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "matches" violates check constraint "check_when_tied_no_winner_and_no_loser"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, 2, 1, 2, t).
```

```
INSERT INTO matches (user_1_id, user_2_id, winner_id, loser_id, tied)
VALUES (1, 2, NULL, NULL, FALSE); -- must be a winner & loser if no tie!
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "matches" violates check constraint "check_when_not_tied_loser_not_null"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1, 2, null, null, f).
```

Check this new one at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=298a1f06302d18b53759d7c8df707430)*

Comment: Btw, comparison to NULL returns `unknown`, not NULL.

Comment: @dnoeth: And `unknown` in [*Three-Value Logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) is represented by `NULL` in SQL.  Check *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c121f3dcb5885db6c7efb2e704aafb7c)*. So, it's equivalent at the end of the day ;-)